# npm install create-react-app my_app got stock on fsevents

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, fsevents

I'm trying to make a react app on my macbook pro 2011 but in first step it got stock.

I installed the latest node version from its [website](https://nodejs.org/en/).

I'm folowing the [react docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) to build my app.

I ran this commands:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

And then it's starting create my app files but stock in fsevents:

```
$ npx create-react-app invoice_generator
Creating a new React app in /Users/system1/w/invoice_generator.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.5
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer 
dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0- 
dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/5] ⠁ fsevents
[-/5] ⠁ waiting...
[-/5] ⠁ waiting...
[-/5] ⠁ waiting...
[-/5] ⠁ waiting...
```

what should I do that I didn't or did I do anthing wrong?

Comment: Are you installing with Root Privileges?

Comment: absolutly my system just have one user and it is admin and I'm using sudo too.so I think this is root yes :)

Comment: try sudo -i then try running installing -g ... commands

Comment: doesn't make any change in installation.again got stock in fsevents

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, when trying to install @react-spring/web. It gets stuck at fsevents

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder A, and then enter the folder A, and run the tutorial command in this folder A without problems.